# Import-Csv with a dialog box

Tags: powershell, active-directory, import-csv

I am trying to add a dialog box into my Import-Csv script in Powershell v7. Basically, I do not want to remember different names of `.csv` files that have been exported from another script, so this will make it a lot easier. I have looked around and could not find anything that relates to what I am getting.

The code I have is this:

```
Write-Host "This will bulk add users to an AD group." -ForegroundColor Yellow
" "

# Import the data from CSV file and assign it to variable
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

$OpenFIleDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
$OpenFileDialog.Filter = "CSV (*.csv) | *.csv"

$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$Path = $OpenFileDialog.Filename

$Users = Import-Csv -Path $Path

# Specify target group where the users will be added to
# You can add the distinguishedName of the group. For example: CN=Pilot,OU=Groups,OU=Company,DC=exoip,DC=local
$Group = Read-Host "Enter in the target group name" 

# Start transcript
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\Output Log\Users Logs\Add-ADUsers.log" -Append -UseMinimalHeader

foreach ($User in $Users) {
    # Retrieve UPN
    $UPN = $User.UserPrincipalName

    # Retrieve UPN related SamAccountName
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$UPN'" | Select-Object SamAccountName

    # User from CSV not in AD
    if ($null -eq $ADUser) {
        Write-Host "$UPN does not exist in AD" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else {
        # Retrieve AD user group membership
        $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $ADUser.SamAccountName | Select-Object Name

        # User already member of group
        if ($ExistingGroups.Name -eq $Group) {
            Write-Host "$UPN already exists in $Group" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
        }
        else {
            # Add user to group
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $ADUser.SamAccountName
            Write-Host "Added $UPN to $Group" -ForeGroundColor Green
        }
    }
}
Stop-Transcript
" "
Remove-Variable -Name Users

Write-Host "Users have finished adding to $group" -ForegroundColor Yellow
" "
}
```

The results of the output is this:

```
The search filter cannot be recognized
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
+ PSComputerName        : localhost
 does not exist in AD
```

Note: "does not exist in AD" has a blank in front of it. I suspect it is because the import is not reading the file, but I cannot make sense of how to fix it.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Show us some of the CSV file you are attempting to read. Does it use the _comma_ as field delimiter or some other character? Does it contain blank fields?

Comment: Your script up to the point where you get the error looks fine. I'm guessing you do not have a column header of 'UserPrincipalName', or are using a non-standard delimiter in your CSV. Try running the script up to where it has completed the `Import-Csv` command, and then check `$Users[0]` to see what properties it has.

Comment: @Theo           
Well I feel dumb; I tried a different csv file and it imported successfully.

The file I was testing with was users exported in a csv from an AD group (didn't work), where as the csv file that did work was from an "all disabled users" export.

I thank you for the point out.